# JS: event target for button with icon

Tags: javascript, jquery, meteor

I simply need to define a click event for this HTML:

```
<button data-method="rotate" class="btn btn-default">
    <i class="fa fa-rotate-left"></i>
</button>
```

**html**

```
Template.page.events({
    'click button': function (event) { 
        var $button     = $(event.target),
            method      = $button.attr('data-method');
    }
});
```

But now there is the problem, that this only works if the user doesn't click on the fa icon, because then the event target is different. In this case `method` will be undefined. 
How can I prevent this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Why not just

```
$(this)   // or $(e.currentTarget)
```

instead of

```
$(event.target)
```

`event.target` points you to the actual element that triggers your event.
But in your case you want that to be a button and all its descendent elements.

Comment: I don' know why, but in my meteor project (client.js event handler) `$(this)` doesn't work.

Comment: Then you could use `$(e.currentTarget)`